# if i!=0 in list comprehension gives syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error, list-comprehension

This question is very much like:
[if/else in Python's list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/python-if-else-in-list-comprehension)
and
[Simple syntax error in Python if else dict comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664841/simple-syntax-error-in-python-if-else-dict-comprehension) . But still i dont understand what error I make here:

```
[i if i!=0 for i in range(2)]
             ^
       syntax error
```

I only want the entries in the list that are non-zero for sparsity.

Comment: Ok done. Thanks for your help. Dont forget to edit your profile description :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Move the `if` to the end. Refer to [The Python Docs entry on List Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
>>> [i for i in range(2) if i!=0] # Or [i for i in range(2) if i]
[1]
```

If you were looking for a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), you could do something like @Martijn pointed out,

```
>>> [i if i!=0 else -1 for i in range(2)]
[-1, 1]
```

If you just want the non zero entities, you could also [`filter(...)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) your list.

```
>>> filter(None, [1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6])
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Thank you for that link to http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: @Leo : Glad to help. Feel Free to accept the answer when the system allows you to. :)

Comment: Yes i was planning to, 7 more minutes. I dont understand why comprehensions need the same order as loops though. Just convention?

Comment: Comprehensions clauses require the order they do because the syntax was calqued from set comprehensions in math, which use that order, and because they're almost entirely equivalent to loops, so it makes sense to make them look alike.

Comment: or `[i if i!=0 else -1 for i in range(2)]` perhaps? The `if` could have been an incomplete conditional expression.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : Thanks. Added that to the answer. :)

Comment: @SukritKalra: it is called a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions); you can link to the documentation perhaps.

Comment: I don't understand last `filter(None, [1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6])` why `None` remove all `0`s **?** What I understand first argument to `filter()` is condition and `bool(None)` == False so it should return empty list.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan : Refer to [The Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter), Quoted, `Note that filter(function, iterable) is equivalent to [item for item in iterable if function(item)] if function is not None and [item for item in iterable if item] if function is None.`

Comment: @SukritKalra Oh I also read: `filter(function, iterable)` : *If function is None, the identity function is assumed, that is, all elements of iterable that are* *`false`* *are removed.* But What is `identity function` ?

Comment: The identity function checks if the item is truth-y or not.

Answer (score 2):

The `if` predicate comes after the specification of the `for i in range(2)` in a list comprehension. You can also have arbitrary number of `if`s.

Answer (score 1):

Switch the `if i!=0` and `for i in range(2)` parts:

```
>>> [i for i in range(2) if i!=0]
[1]
>>>
```